# Search in different models depending on condition [ Ruby on Rails ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, controller

I am new in web development and RoR in particular, so I am sorry if this question is too obvious. Anyway, I am trying to create a real estate web site, just to see what it all takes to do it, and I got stuck on searching. I have a few models, every for each kind of real estate, like apartment, office, garage and etc, and when the user searches an apartment, it should use "Apartment" model to search in, if she searches a garage, then it should search in "garage" model and so on. So, could you help me and give me any hint what do I put in the controller?

Comment: You could use a select box to select the "kind of object searched" and a simple input type text to write the keywords to find "the object(s) searched"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a mapping from user's input to classes.

```
SEARCH_TYPES = { 'apartment' => Flat, 'garage' => Garage, 'house' => House }
```

Determine the Class from user's input and use finder methods like you always do.

```
def search
  if klass = SEARCH_TYPES[params[:search][:type]]
    klass.where(params[:search])
  else
    # handle no matching Class for type of search
  end
end
```

What not do: Try to get the Class directly from the params.

Comment: Would you create a new model to do this or put this in your controller?

Comment: @HeliosdeGuerra: It depends. On the one hand a delegating class would be better for readability and tests. But on the other hand it is just a method and a constant. Short: unless it gets more code or should be reused I would put is in the controller.